# How to use the 'package:' module as non-root user?

Tags: ansible

I want a playbook to validate that some packages are installed and fail that system if they are not.  I thought I could use the `package:` module as a non-root user and have it validate the packages were installed.

I thought that the `idempotency` of Ansible would permit (actually encourage) this usage.  Is this a bug or enhancement that I should escalate, or am I overlooking something simple to achieve this?

Here is my playbook for testing:

```
---
- name: Show package module non-root usage
  hosts: all
  become: false

  tasks:
  - name: Check that a packages is installed
    package:
      name:
        - vim-common
      state: installed
```

As a normal user I can see that `vim-common` is installed:

```
$ rpm -qa vim-common
vim-common-8.0.1763-15.el8.x86_64

$ dnf list vim-common
Not root, Subscription Management repositories not updated
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:29 ago on Thu 21 Jan 2021 12:50:56 PM CST.
Installed Packages
vim-common.x86_64                                  2:8.0.1763-15.el8                                  @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
$
```

But when I run the playbook I get this error instead of a "success" result:

```
$ ansible-playbook package_check.yml -i localhost, --connection=local

PLAY [Show package module non-root usage] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that a packages is installed] *********************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "This command has to be run under the root user.", "results": []}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$
```

As expected, when I run it as root it works properly:

```
$ sudo ansible-playbook package_check.yml -i localhost, --connection=local

PLAY [Show package module non-root usage] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that a packages is installed] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$
```

My system is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)` with Ansible 2.10:

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.10.4
  config file = /home/dan/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/dan/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Aug 18 2020, 08:33:21) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

## Update #1

Searching through the Ansible code, the `dnf.py` module is where this comes from:

```
$ egrep -C3 "This command has to be run under the root user." /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/dnf.py
            # before running it.
            if not dnf.util.am_i_root():
                self.module.fail_json(
                    msg="This command has to be run under the root user.",
                    results=[],
                )
            self.base = self._base(
$
```

If I comment out that root check block:

```
$ egrep -C3 "This command has to be run under the root user." /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/dnf.py
            # before running it.
#            if not dnf.util.am_i_root():
#                self.module.fail_json(
#                    msg="This command has to be run under the root user.",
#                    results=[],
#                )
            self.base = self._base(
$
```

I can now run the playbook and it confirms the package is installed without needing root permissions:

```
$ ansible-playbook package_check.yml -i localhost, --connection=local

PLAY [Show package module non-root usage] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that a packages is installed] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$
```

## Update #2

Slightly modifying the playbook to check an installed and a missing package:

```
$ cat package_check.yml
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
---
- name: Show package module non-root usage
  hosts: all
  become: false

  tasks:
  - name: Check that VIM common is installed
    package:
      name:
        - vim-common
      state: installed

  - name: Check that EMACS is installed
    package:
      name:
        - vim-common
        - emacs
      state: installed

$
```

Now we get a success on the first and a failure on the second:

```
$ ansible-playbook package_check.yml -i localhost, --connection=local

PLAY [Show package module non-root usage] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that VIM common is installed] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that EMACS is installed] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "2021-01-21 13:27:23,224 [ERROR] dnf.py:724879:MainThread @logutil.py:194 - [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log' - Further logging output will be written to stderr\n2021-01-21 13:27:23,233 [ERROR] dnf.py:724879:MainThread @identity.py:156 - Reload of consumer identity cert /etc/pki/consumer/cert.pem raised an exception with msg: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/pki/consumer/key.pem'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/dan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611257242.3944752-724867-4205539601634/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/dan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611257242.3944752-724867-4205539601634/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/dan/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1611257242.3944752-724867-4205539601634/AnsiballZ_dnf.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.dnf', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload_ewju4h_n/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1330, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload_ewju4h_n/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1319, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload_ewju4h_n/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1294, in run\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload_ewju4h_n/ansible_ansible.legacy.dnf_payload.zip/ansible/modules/dnf.py\", line 1213, in ensure\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py\", line 882, in do_transaction\n    tid = self._run_transaction(cb=cb)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py\", line 955, in _run_transaction\n    tid = self.history.beg(rpmdbv, using_pkgs, [], cmdline, comment)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py\", line 473, in beg\n    comment)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py\", line 763, in beginTransaction\n    return _transaction.Swdb_beginTransaction(self, *args)\nlibdnf._error.Error: SQLite error on \"/var/lib/dnf/history.sqlite\": Reading a row failed: attempt to write a readonly database\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$
```

And running as root works as expected:

```
$ sudo ansible-playbook package_check.yml -i localhost, --connection=local

PLAY [Show package module non-root usage] *********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that VIM common is installed] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check that EMACS is installed] **************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `state: installed` is meant to install the package if it does not exists. So, this is not strictly equal to polling your package manager for a packet.

In order to do this, you will have to use the [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html) gatherer.
Then you can easily use [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) on that same task if the package(s) you expect are not present.

Here would be an example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - package_facts:
      failed_when: "'apache2' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```

---

In order to solve the use case you stated in the comment below, you can always use the variable [`ansible_check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#skipping-tasks-or-ignoring-errors-in-check-mode):

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - package_facts:
      failed_when: "'apache2' not in ansible_facts.packages"
      when: ansible_check_mode

    - package:
        name: apache2
      when: not ansible_check_mode
```

Comment: Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε - this seems anti-pattern for Ansible.  It seems like the "package:" module should have an internal "package_facts" call and only attempt to install the packages requested that aren't returned in the facts package list.

This permits my system admin team to run the playbook to install and get things setup, and the developers or auditors to run the same playbook and validate that everything is as it should be.  We could have the auditors run the playbook with root permissions and ask them to use `--check` but that's a big risk exposure to other issues.

Comment: Well no, strictly speaking, idempotency do not apply here. You cannot possibly want idempotency if the task you are aiming to run is never going to change anything anyway. So what you really need here is a fact.

Comment: And to solve your specific use case you can use `ansible_check_mode`, see updated answer.